# Setting EmptyListView in ListFragment does not work the way intended

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I am trying to set the Empty view for a custom ListFragment to be displayed when the list is empty programatically. The Xml file for the empty layout is as follow. Just a TextView.

(list_empty_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center"
>

<TextView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No Items"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:gravity="center"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used the following code in my ListFragment to set the EmptyView. I just guessed it is the right spot to set it because before this point the ListView is not instantiated so an error is thrown if i call getListView()

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View v=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_empty_view, null);
    getListView().setEmptyView(v);
}
```

This does not show the EmptyView when the list is empty so I thought the problem is with providing null for the root Parameter in inflate method. So I replaced null with something like this found on an another answer.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        View v=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_empty_view, (ViewGroup)getListView().getParent());
        getListView().setEmptyView(v);

    }
```

This works fine and the List is now showing the previous layout when it is empty but when i add an item to my list the item is not appearing in the list. Just a blank screen. Not even the EmptyView layout which i just set.

I am completely clueless about the problem as i replaced null with something which i don't grasp completely as well. So any help with all the steps i used will be appreciated as I am a newbie in android right now. I just want to add the empty layout programmtically because if this works i am planning to add more things to empty layout (Buttons, ImageViews etc)

Comment: Do you have a custom layout for your list fragment?

Comment: Yes it is a custom List.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (in my experience at least) to work with `ListFragment` is to provide a custom layout instead of letting it use the default layout. [`The documentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) shows a pretty straightforward example of how to specify a layout for your `ListFragment`; you need only make sure to inflate it and return it in `onCreateView()`:

`res/layout/my_list_fragment.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ... />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="No Items"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, container, false);
    ...
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Hello Thanks a lot for answering. But the thing is i want to do it programatically. Is there any reliable way of doing it as well? I have already defined the layout of my custom List Items and inflated it using getView method of ListFragment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the view you inflated for the empty view isn't actually part of the view hierarchy (e.g. you never call `someViewGroup.addView(emptyView)`). When the list has no items, since it has an empty view, the `ListView` becomes `GONE` and the empty view becomes `VISIBLE`, but if it's not in the view hierarchy then it will never be seen, hence the blank screen.

Another option is to use just an empty `FrameLayout` (or some other ViewGroup) as the empty view in the layout XML and programmatically add views to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The hint Given by Karakuri was very helpful. The problem really was that I was not adding the empty list view to view hierarchy of the ListFragment and hence it was not able to replace it afterwards correctly. Replaced my code with this and it worked.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.list_empty_view, null);
    ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(v);
    getListView().setEmptyView(v);
}
```